# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object Twitter API

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-oauth, tweets

I am using twitter API to get the tweets on website, sometimes it shows good and than suddenly its stop showing error..

**This error comes when its stops working:**

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in public_html/wp-content/themes/sandra/TwitterModel.php on line 26
```

Here is my code:

```
require("TwitterModel.php");
$tw = new TwitterModel();
$t = $tw->getTweets("sandrasflower");
echo "<div>";
foreach($t['tweets'] as $date=>$tweet) 
{
   echo "<div class='tweet'>";
   echo $tweet . "<br />" . date("jS F Y", strtotime($date));
   echo "</div>";
}
```

Please help me somebody...

TwitterModel.php file code:

```
<?php

    class TwitterModel {

        protected $token        = "1949108046-8jQwOMdqLSw86n2UZvFx0RlkquyKDEwndxdTMfN";
        protected $token_secret     = "PE1EIHRGpt8OHkk5Okc9HLUE2ilUL1UYP4u3GTDucOPCG";
        protected $consumer_key     = "9b7Ww9SM1AdeiVhOoYuenDsRS";
        protected $consumer_secret  = "nhAASYEa4epSribnb1kSPqtZVFMih4eXYJVWgm5W5VBTCnuOjC";

        protected $host             = 'api.twitter.com';
        protected $method           = 'GET';
        protected $path             = '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'; // api call path

        # Get the last 5 tweets for this screen name
        public function getTweets($user) {
            $query = array( // query parameters
                'screen_name' => $user,
                'count' => '4'
            );

            $twitter_data = $this->request($query);

            $name = "";
            $tweets = array();
            foreach ($twitter_data as $value) {
                $name = $value->user->name;
                $tweetout = "";
                $tweetout .= preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $value->text) . "<br />";
                $tweetout = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $tweetout);
                $tweetout = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $tweetout);
                $tweets[$value->created_at] = $tweetout;
            }

            if(is_array($tweets) && !empty($tweets)) {
                return array("name" => $value->user->name, "image" => $value->user->profile_image_url, "tweets" => $tweets);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function request($query) {
            $oauth = array(
                'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->consumer_key,
                'oauth_token' => $this->token,
                'oauth_nonce' => (string)mt_rand(), // a stronger nonce is recommended
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_version' => '1.0'
            );

            $oauth = array_map("rawurlencode", $oauth); // must be encoded before sorting
            $query = array_map("rawurlencode", $query);

            $arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort

            asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
            ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)

            // http_build_query automatically encodes, but our parameters
            // are already encoded, and must be by this point, so we undo
            // the encoding step
            $querystring = urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));

            $this->url = "https://$this->host$this->path";

            // mash everything together for the text to hash
            $base_string = $this->method."&".rawurlencode($this->url)."&".rawurlencode($querystring);

            // same with the key
            $key = rawurlencode($this->consumer_secret)."&".rawurlencode($this->token_secret);

            // generate the hash
            $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)));

            // this time we're using a normal GET query, and we're only encoding the query params
            // (without the oauth params)
            $this->url .= "?".http_build_query($query);
            $this->url = str_replace("&amp;","&",$this->url); //Patch by @Frewuill

            $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $signature; // don't want to abandon all that work!
            ksort($oauth); // probably not necessary, but twitter's demo does it

            // also not necessary, but twitter's demo does this too
            function add_quotes($str) { return '"'.$str.'"'; }
            $oauth = array_map("add_quotes", $oauth);

            // this is the full value of the Authorization line
            $auth = "OAuth " . urldecode(http_build_query($oauth, '', ', '));

            // if you're doing post, you need to skip the GET building above
            // and instead supply query parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
            $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
                              //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                              CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
                              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

            // do our business
            $feed = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
            $json = curl_exec($feed);
            curl_close($feed);

            $twitter_data = json_decode($json);
            return $twitter_data;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Which line is line 26? The error refers to the fact that you are trying to access an object that doesn't exist. This is most commonly due to the data been an array and not an object.

Comment: but the reason is sometimes its works fine and sometimes its start showing error. why is that so?

Comment: If you let me know which line of code is on line 26 then we can start to debug this problem. With error logging turned on, is there any Twitter response code errors?

Comment: here is line 26 : $name = $value->user->name; on "TwitterModel.php"

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the code of `TwitterModel.php`.

Comment: and when you do a var_dump() or print_r() of $value does it indeed contain the object of `->user->name`?

Comment: You usually need to set up an OAuth token to get data from Twitter, see https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview - does your code already do this?

Comment: @Monkeybrain how can i attach it over herE?

Comment: yes its do the OAuth Token and its added successfully

Comment: I don't think Stack Exchange allows you to upload files, you'll have to post the code. If it's massive, maybe upload it to a public github or bitbucket repo (as long as you own the rights to display it publicly of course).

Comment: @Monkeybrain i have updated the post with the code.. can you please check and let me know issue.. if its showing good, keep on refreshing the browser and it will start displaying error after some time

Comment: @Monkeybrain here is page link : you can check its showing error at bottom:http://www.sandrasflowerstudio.co.uk/wedding-flowers/venues/judges-lodgings/

Comment: I'll take a look - I might be a while ...

Comment: okay m waiting buddy

Comment: Is `TwitterModel.php` a piece of code that you are developing, or a component from a commercial WordPress theme or plugin?

Comment: You are using `$value` outside the `foreach`-loop it is created/defined in.

Comment: Its a componetnt or API code i didn't developed it. i just write top most code to retereive tweets..

Comment: @RST - that's true but his error is inside the foreach loop.

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - your code runs successfully from the command line. There may be something going on with your webserver or WordPress installation?

Comment: okay thanks, i will check it..

Comment: Suggest you put some debugging lines in `TwitterModel.php` so that you get some useful info in your webserver logs during the execution of`TwitterModel->request`, to narrow down which part of it is failing. WAIT NEWS FLASH - I am now getting your errors from my command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error being sent back from your calls to Twitter:

```
class stdClass#2 (1) {
  public $errors =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#3 (2) {
      public $message =>
      string(19) "Rate limit exceeded"
      public $code =>
      int(88)
    }
  }
}
```

So you are making API calls more frequently than is allowed. 
See https://blog.twitter.com/2008/what-does-rate-limit-exceeded-mean-updated

It's not a code problem.

Comment: Okay it means the APi which is used is not not development api, its just for testing? can you send me link from where i can get development real account APi key & Secret Key?

Comment: I don't think it means that. I think Twitter only allows you to make a certain number of requests in a given time interval, and after that, it will send you this error. If all you want to do is display the Twitter timeline on your website, it might be better to do it client-side using https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines.